# Classifying dots in matrix (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have big matrix, like 600x600 with 9 dots in 9 same sectors(# like tic-tac-toe). 
I need to turn it to 3x3 array with iDs of dots in this sectors, like:
[[id2,id1,id5],[id4,id6,id7],[id3,id8,id9]]
Dividing plane in 9 small planes goes really bad. I need something like relative positions, and dont know even the worlds I need to google

```
def classificator(val):
    global A
    global closed
    height, width = map(int, closed.shape)
    h1 = height // 3
    w1 = width // 3
    h2 = height // 3 * 2
    w2 = width // 3 * 2
    for x in range(len(val)):
        xcoord = val[x][0]
        ycoord = val[x][1]
        if 0 <= val[x][0] < h1 and 0 <= val[x][1] < w1 and A[0, 0] == '_': #top left X
            A[0, 0] = val[x][2]
```

Comment: Let's say your matrix is not 600x600 but 6x6. Would you add this matrix (with dots) along with a working code to your question in order to let us understand your problem better?

Comment: This matrix is
[[243, 173, 'o'], ... , [x, y, 'str']]
x coord left ->rigth
y coord top ->bot

Comment: To get good answers you have to improve your question. See this: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Please try to give more details about your problem and maybe a (small) example of one input and its output. This big matrix, is it a NumPy array or a nested Python list? Does it contains numbers, or something else? What are these "dots", values in the matrix? What do you mean by "9 same sectors"? Are these parts of the matrix? What is the "plane", how do you "divide the plane" and why does it go bad? In your code, the input does not seem to be the big matrix, but a list of tuples each having two coordinates and a string, so what is really the input and the expected output for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Following from the comments above.  This is still asking for clarification but shows a way of interpreting your question.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: data_in=np.fromfunction(lambda r, c: 10*r+c, (6, 6))
        # Create an array where the vales give a indication of where they are in the array.

In [3]: data_in
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15.],
       [20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25.],
       [30., 31., 32., 33., 34., 35.],
       [40., 41., 42., 43., 44., 45.],
       [50., 51., 52., 53., 54., 55.]])

In [4]: slices=[np.s_[0:3], np.s_[3:6] ]

In [5]: slices
Out[5]: [slice(0, 3, None), slice(3, 6, None)]

In [8]: result=np.zeros((4,3,3), dtype=np.int32)

In [9]: ix=0

In [12]: for rows in slices:
    ...:     for columns in slices:
    ...:         result[ix,:,:]=data_in[rows, columns]
    ...:         ix+=1
    ...:         

In [13]: result
Out[13]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [10, 11, 12],    # Top Left in data_in
        [20, 21, 22]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [13, 14, 15],    # Top Right in data_in            
        [23, 24, 25]],

       [[30, 31, 32],
        [40, 41, 42],    # Bottom Left in data_in
        [50, 51, 52]],

       [[33, 34, 35],
        [43, 44, 45],    # Bottom Right in data_in
        [53, 54, 55]]], dtype=int32)
```

Can you use it as a basis to explain what you expect to see?
If your input data was only 6 by 6 what would it look like and what would you expect to see coming out?

Edits: Two typos corrected.